# Django ORM - selecting related records by setting criteria on some fields but excluding current record from returned records

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I am using Django 3.2

I am writing a function to return related records when an object is retrieved from the database.

I am using the tags field (a `TaggitManager` instance) to determine which records are related. I then want to remove (i.e. exclude the current record) from the set of related records.

Here is the line of code that is supposed to return objects related (in terms of tags):

```
object = self.get_object()
object_tag_fields = [x.name.strip() for x in object.tags.get_queryset()]

if object_tag_fields:
    query_match = Q()
    
    for tag_field in object_tag_fields:
        query_match |= Q(tags__name__contains=tag_field)

    related_foos = Foo.objects.filter(query_match).exclude(id=object.id).distinct()
```

Howerver, when I run the above code, it ALWAYS includes the fetched object, in the set of related objects.

I have also tried the following (to no avail):

> Foo.objects.exclude(id=object.id).filter(query_match).distinct()

> Foo.objects.filter(~Q(id=object.id)).filter(query_match).distinct()

Both statements include the fetched object in the set of related objects.

How do I correct the query so that all records that are related (by tag) are returned - EXCLUDING the current fetched object?

Comment: How about Foo.objects.filter(query_match).distinct().difference(Foo.objects.get(id=object.id))

Comment: You could use [similar_objects()](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects)? You would need to add a custom through table though

Comment: @IainShelvington Could you elaborate with an example, what you mean by a through table? I hadn't come across `similar_objects()` before - but the Taggit documentation does not provide an example where the similar objects are restricted to one model type.

Comment: @EneP I haven't tried that - but my dbadmin-foo is telling me that would result in a lot of inefficient queries being shunted to the DB (think OUTER JOINs etc.). Is there anyway I can check out the SQL that statement generates?

Comment: print( my_queryset.query )